# Custom Authorize Attribute Redirect When UnAuthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, forms-authentication

In my C# MVC4 application, I am performing a couple different redirect to actions from inside of a custom authorize attribute dependent upon if the user is logged in, in a certain role, etc.

I've placed the authorize attribute above one of my action results.  If the user is not logged in or not authenticated or logged in but not a member of either group that I check against, I want the code within the action result to be performed.  If the user is logged in and is a member of either group, I want a redirect to another action to occur (this is currently working).

With my current code, those that are logged in and within a specified group are re-directed as desired.  All those listed in the other categories, cause my AuthorizationContext to be null.  Knowing that when this is null HandleUnauthorizedRequest is called, I have attempted to override it to allow access to the original actionresult but cant figure it out.

No matter what I try I receive the error:  `Object Reference not set to an instance of an object` on the line with:  `filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(`

My authorize attribute code is below:

```
     public class AuthorizeEditAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
        {
            public string hName { get; set; }
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

            // Check if user is authenticated and if this action requires authorization
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
                && filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), true)
                || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), true))
            {
                List<object> attributes = new List<object>(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), true));
                attributes.AddRange(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), true));


                hName = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("hSearch").AttemptedValue;


                // Check all authorzation attributes
                foreach (var attribute in attributes)
                {

                    var authAttribute = attribute as AuthorizeAttribute;
                    if (authAttribute != null)
                    {
                        if ((filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("TCL-CAdmin")) || (filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("TCL-C Group")))
                        {

                            // User is not authorized to perform edits so redirect to Index_Perm ActionResult
                            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                new RouteValueDictionary 
                            {
                                //{ "area", "" },
                                { "controller", "Home" },
                                { "action", "Index_Perm" },
                                { "hSearch", hName.ToString() }
                            });
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                               new RouteValueDictionary 
                            {
                                //{ "area", "" },
                                { "controller", "Home" },
                                { "action", "Index" },
                                { "hSearch", hName.ToString() }
                            });
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {

                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
   new RouteValueDictionary 
                            {
                                { "controller", "Home" },
                                { "action", "Index" },
                                { "hSearch", hName.ToString() }
                            });
            }
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {

                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
 new RouteValueDictionary 
                            {
                                { "controller", "Home" },
                                { "action", "Index" },
                                { "hSearch", hName.ToString() }
                            });
        }
    }
}
```

Rather than overriding HandleUnauthorizedRequest, I have also tried modifying the beginning portion of OnAuthorization to look like this:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {

            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

            if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
   new RouteValueDictionary 
                            {
                                { "controller", "Home" },
                                { "action", "Index" },
                                { "hSearch", hName.ToString() }
                            });
            }
```

and I still receive the same warning about object reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the route value "hSearch," which was being assigned the value of hName.  hName was always null in each of my attempts because I was not setting its value until the line:  `hName = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("hSearch").AttemptedValue;` which was never being hit.